# Tomcat Server 6 won't start on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat6, openbravo

i am currently taking a course on Openbravo ERP and i run it through my Tomcat server, and as per requirement i downloaded iReports and did some exercises (i don't know if it has anything to do with it) and out of the blue, my server wouldn't start, this is the log i get:

```
    Feb 06, 2014 12:29:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
    INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Java\jre7\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Java/jdk/bin/../jre/bin/server;C:/Java/jdk/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Java/jdk/bin/../jre/lib/amd64;C:\Apache\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\;C:\Java\jdk\bin;C:\Apache\apache-ant-1.7.1\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\ThinPrint\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Users\tzivia\Desktop\eclipse;;.
Feb 06, 2014 12:29:56 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:openbravo' did not find a matching property.
Feb 06, 2014 12:29:56 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context/Loader} Setting property 'useSystemClassLoaderAsParent' to 'false' did not find a matching property.
Feb 06, 2014 12:29:57 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Feb 06, 2014 12:29:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2140 ms
Feb 06, 2014 12:29:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Feb 06, 2014 12:29:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.32
Feb 06, 2014 12:30:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.openbravo.dal.core.DalContextListener
org.openbravo.base.exception.OBException: org.openbravo.base.exception.OBException: Failed to load reference classes
    at org.openbravo.base.model.ModelProvider.refresh(ModelProvider.java:128)
    at org.openbravo.dal.core.DalLayerInitializer.initialize(DalLayerInitializer.java:65)
    at org.openbravo.dal.core.DalContextListener.contextInitialized(DalContextListener.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4704)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: org.openbravo.base.exception.OBException: Failed to load reference classes
    at org.openbravo.base.model.ModelProvider.initializeReferenceClasses(ModelProvider.java:379)
    at org.openbravo.base.model.ModelProvider.initialize(ModelProvider.java:155)
    at org.openbravo.base.model.ModelProvider.getModel(ModelProvider.java:141)
    at org.openbravo.base.model.ModelProvider.refresh(ModelProvider.java:126)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: org.openbravo.exception.NoConnectionAvailableException: There are no connections available in jdbc:apache:commons:dbcp:openbravo_myPool
    at org.openbravo.database.ConnectionProviderImpl.getNewConnection(ConnectionProviderImpl.java:239)
    at org.openbravo.database.ConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(ConnectionProviderImpl.java:211)
    at org.openbravo.database.ConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(ConnectionProviderImpl.java:196)
    at org.openbravo.base.model.ModelProvider.initializeReferenceClasses(ModelProvider.java:357)
    ... 20 more

Feb 06, 2014 12:30:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.openbravo.client.kernel.KernelContextListener
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openbravo.client.kernel.KernelInitializer.setInterceptor(KernelInitializer.java:58)
    at org.openbravo.client.kernel.KernelInitializer.initialize(KernelInitializer.java:48)
    at org.openbravo.client.kernel.org$jboss$weld$bean-flat-ManagedBean-class_org$openbravo$client$kernel$KernelInitializer_$$_WeldClientProxy.initialize(org$jboss$weld$bean-flat-ManagedBean-class_org$openbravo$client$kernel$KernelInitializer_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at org.openbravo.client.kernel.KernelContextListener.contextInitialized(KernelContextListener.java:37)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4704)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

Feb 06, 2014 12:30:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Feb 06, 2014 12:30:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/openbravo] startup failed due to previous errors
Feb 06, 2014 12:30:47 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/openbravo] registered the JDBC driver [oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Feb 06, 2014 12:30:47 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/openbravo] registered the JDBC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Feb 06, 2014 12:30:47 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/openbravo] registered the JDBC driver [org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Feb 06, 2014 12:30:47 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/openbravo] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Feb 06, 2014 12:30:47 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/openbravo] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Feb 06, 2014 12:30:47 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/openbravo] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-3] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Feb 06, 2014 12:30:47 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/openbravo] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Feb 06, 2014 12:30:47 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/openbravo] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Feb 06, 2014 12:30:47 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/openbravo] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-6] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Feb 06, 2014 12:30:47 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/openbravo] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-7] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Feb 06, 2014 12:30:47 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/openbravo] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-8] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Feb 06, 2014 12:30:47 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/openbravo] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-9] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Feb 06, 2014 12:30:47 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/openbravo] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-10] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Feb 06, 2014 12:30:47 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/openbravo] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Feb 06, 2014 12:30:48 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Feb 06, 2014 12:30:48 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Feb 06, 2014 12:30:48 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/30  config=null
Feb 06, 2014 12:30:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 50904 ms
log4j:ERROR Error occured while converting date.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.getChars(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.getChars(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.ISO8601DateFormat.format(ISO8601DateFormat.java:130)
    at java.text.DateFormat.format(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.PatternParser$DatePatternConverter.convert(PatternParser.java:443)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.PatternConverter.format(PatternConverter.java:65)
    at org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout.format(PatternLayout.java:506)
    at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.subAppend(WriterAppender.java:310)
    at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.subAppend(RollingFileAppender.java:276)
    at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.append(WriterAppender.java:162)
    at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:856)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.error(Log4JLogger.java:257)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler$1.run(QuartzScheduler.java:478)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Feb 06, 2014 12:31:12 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load org.quartz.utils.ExceptionHelper.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1566)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.quartz.SchedulerException.getUnderlyingException(SchedulerException.java:169)
    at org.quartz.SchedulerException.toString(SchedulerException.java:265)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.println(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintWriter.println(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:654)
    at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:720)
    at org.quartz.SchedulerException.printStackTrace(SchedulerException.java:325)
    at org.apache.log4j.DefaultThrowableRenderer.render(DefaultThrowableRenderer.java:60)
    at org.apache.log4j.spi.ThrowableInformation.getThrowableStrRep(ThrowableInformation.java:87)
    at org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent.getThrowableStrRep(LoggingEvent.java:413)
    at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.subAppend(WriterAppender.java:313)
    at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.subAppend(RollingFileAppender.java:276)
    at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.append(WriterAppender.java:162)
    at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:856)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.error(Log4JLogger.java:257)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler$1.run(QuartzScheduler.java:478)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/quartz/utils/ExceptionHelper
    at org.quartz.SchedulerException.getUnderlyingException(SchedulerException.java:169)
    at org.quartz.SchedulerException.toString(SchedulerException.java:265)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.println(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintWriter.println(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:654)
    at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:720)
    at org.quartz.SchedulerException.printStackTrace(SchedulerException.java:325)
    at org.apache.log4j.DefaultThrowableRenderer.render(DefaultThrowableRenderer.java:60)
    at org.apache.log4j.spi.ThrowableInformation.getThrowableStrRep(ThrowableInformation.java:87)
    at org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent.getThrowableStrRep(LoggingEvent.java:413)
    at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.subAppend(WriterAppender.java:313)
    at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.subAppend(RollingFileAppender.java:276)
    at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.append(WriterAppender.java:162)
    at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:856)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.error(Log4JLogger.java:257)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler$1.run(QuartzScheduler.java:478)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.quartz.utils.ExceptionHelper
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    ... 22 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Your application is generating null pointer exception when deployed on server.
check the code and find out why its happening. Cannot tell more than that just from the error log...